# How to change the page urls in grav CMS

Tags: url, content-management-system, grav

URLs are automatically taken from folder structure. I want to change URLs to SEO-friendly URLs. Can anyone help me to do so. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In the **Configuration** of your site go to **Redirects and Routes** and add a route (SEO-friendly URL) to the desired page. (Make sure you have the Admin plugin installed!)

More info in the excellent documentation, chapter [Redirects and Routes](https://learn.getgrav.org/admin-panel/configuration-site#redirects-and-routes)

Comment: I would add that you can change the slug of every page :
https://learn.getgrav.org/content/headers#slug